# Dimension of fibres of reducible varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Chapter IV of the book, Algebraic Geometry; An Introduction by Daniel Perrin,  he showed the following (the base field is algebraically closed):

> Corollary 3.8. 
>   Let $\varphi:X\to Y$ be a morphism of algebraic varieties.
>
> (1) Assume that all the fibres of $\varphi$ are of dimension $\leq r$. 
>   Then $\dim X \leq r + \dim Y$.
>
> (2) Assume that $\varphi$ is dominant and all the nonempty fibres of $\varphi$ are of dimension $r$. Then $\dim X = r + \dim Y$.

I understand (1) but I do not understand the proof of $(2)$.

> Proof of $(2)$ We decompose $Y$ into irreducible components, $Y = Y_1 \cup \cdots \cup Y_n$. Let $Y_i$ be a component of $Y$ of dimension $\dim Y$. The restriction $\varphi:\varphi^{-1}(Y_i) \to Y_i$ is dominant (consider the nonempty open set $Y_i \setminus \bigcup_{j\neq i}Y_j$). We then decompose $\varphi^{-1}(Y_i) = \bigcup_j X_{i,j}$ into irreducible components. 
>   *After possibly removing components we can assume that all the sets $X_{i,j}$ dominate $Y_i$.* If the dimensions of all the $X_{i,j}$ are $< r + \dim Y$, then dimension theorem of generic fibres of irreducible varieties applied to the restriction $\varphi:X_{i,j}\to Y_i$ shows that the general fibre of $\varphi^{-1}(Y_i)\to Y_i$ is of dimension $<r$ (originally $>r$ but should be a typo, comments by me), which is impossible.

Why can we assume all the sets $X_{i,j}$ dominate $Y_i$?

I have understood that there exists $X_{i,k}$ such that $\overline{\varphi(X_{i,k})}=Y_i$ since $Y_i$ is irreducible.
Now assume $\dim X_{i,j}<\dim Y + r$ for all $X_{i,j}$.
For a general $y\in \overline{\varphi(X_{i,j})}$, we have 
$$\dim Y + r > \dim X_{i,j} = \dim \overline{\varphi(X_{i,j})} + \dim (\varphi^{-1}(y)\cap X_{i,j})$$
 and thus 
$$\dim (\varphi^{-1}(y)\cap X_{i,j}) < \dim Y_i - \dim \overline{\varphi(X_{i,j})} + r.$$
If $\overline{\varphi(X_{i,j})}=Y_i$,
$$\dim (\varphi^{-1}(y)\cap X_{i,k}) < r.$$

However if $\overline{\varphi(X_{i,j})}\subsetneq Y_i$, 
the above inequality does not seem to necessarily hold.
How can we get $\dim\varphi^{-1}(y)<r$?